# w3c compliance - html 5 - "Error: The document content type is not HTML : undefined"

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Consider the following html5 file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        test
    </body>
</html>
```

I am validating it using [Html Validator (0.9.7.4)](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/) which is installed in Firefox(version 51) as an add on.

It shows the following error

[image]

I have pasted the code https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea and there is no issue shown here.

Is this an issue with the plugin or am i missing some meta data in my code?

Please help

Comment: It's a problem with the plugin. There's plenty of contact information on the site you linked to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MiKe is right, it's a problem with the plugin. It's been this way for a while now. I hope it will be fixed in the next update, but it hasn't been updated in like a year so who knows when that will be.

Update: It's fixed in the 09.7.7 beta version: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/versions/beta